# How to find the function's equation using Neural Network (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for some guidance as apparently there isn't too much information about it.
I would like to know, if there's any documentation available to extract an function's equation from a given a dataset, or if someone can guide me how to obtain the equation to get all the points from a given data.

I know there are 2 methods:

- Universal Approximation Universal Approximation.
- Regression using Neural Networks

In both cases, it seems that doesn't fits what I need do it. Basically I have this function:

[image: Function]

In which I would like to obtain an equation that satisfies this function F(x) = ?

Reducing the noise, I got the following graph:

[image: Smooth graph]

My question is: is it possible to obtain a function through the graph only?

The input data is just a velocity vector in kilometers per hour.

Comment: "obtain an equation that satisfies this function" - a neural network _is_ a somewhat fancy function that you can write down as a pretty long equation. By fitting a neural network to data you obtain a function (the network) that approximates the actual process which generated the data.

Comment: Thanks for answering me! 

I understand, that neural networks are able to approximate any given function, but in no video that I could find, in the end it demonstrates a function given the degree and its variables as f(x) = ax**7 + bx**4 - 3x**3..etc

Following this line of reasoning, is there any documentation that demonstrates it or do you recommend a course to learn how to implement this methodology?

Comment: As shown [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#warm_up_a_fast_matrix-based_approach_to_computing_the_output_from_a_neural_network), for example, the output of a single layer is `f(W*X + b)`, where `X` is the output of the previous layer. You could unroll this and end up with a huge scary formula: it can be really, really long and absolutely meaningless to a human.